# How can you search a UITextFields in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have UIScrollView. It added several UIView. In UIView TextField added. How do I add all the TextField array?

```
for (int i=0; i < numMaysDayVal; i++) {

        backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (60*(i)), 320, 60)];

        myTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,15, 300, 35)];

        myTextField.delegate = self;

        [backView addSubview:myTextField];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:backView];

        scrollHeight = i;

    }

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, scrollHeight*60 + 80)];

}
```

Comment: you need to be a lot more detailed and specific for anyone to be able to help you

Comment: Show code. How do you create all these text fields?

Comment: объясни по русски, наверное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you really want? You added them already as far as I can see. 
Do you mean by "search them" that you want to refer to them later on (e.g. to fetch the values)?

If so then there are several possible solutions.

1. You could add a NSMutableArray as local variable to your view controller to which you add all the text fields.
2. Or you assign 10000+i as tag to the text fields (myTextFild.tag = 10000+i). And later search for the text view by their tag (self.scrollview.viewWithTag(10000+i). Why 10000+i? That is because the default value for tag is 0. If you start off setting tags to the subviews with i only then it would be hard to identify the one with the tag 0 because all the other subviews of the scrollview would have that value too.